# Insert vb.net into sql w/comboBox and datetimepicker

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox, datetimepicker

**what am I doing wrong**??? I have 7 textbox, 1 datetimepicker and 1 combobox in my form. When I click the save button, It doesn't do nothing, just like a new button without code, not even the customer saved message or error message.

```
    Private Sub btnSaveCust_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveCust.Click
    Try
        Dim sex As String
        sex = ""
        If cbSex.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            sex = cbSex.Items(cbSex.SelectedValue).ToString
        End If

        Dim conex As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BD_;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tableCustomer WHERE ID=@ID"
        Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conex)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Today date]", txtToday.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", txtMiddle.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Last name]", txtLastName.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birth", DateTimePickerBirth.Value)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", cbSex.SelectedValue)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E-mail", txtEmail.Text)
        conex.Open()

        Using read As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            If read.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("ID '" & txtID.Text & "' already in DB. Enter another ID", MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                txtID.Focus()
            Else
                read.Close()
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand _
                                        ("Insert into [BD_].[dbo].[tableCustomer] ([ID],[Today date],[Name],[Middlename],[Last name],[Birth],[Age],[Sex],[Phone],[E-mail]) values ('" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtToday.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtMiddle.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + DateTimePickerBirth.ToString("dd MM yyyy") + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + sex + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "')", conex)
                conex.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Customer '" & txtName.Text & "' saved.", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                conex.Close()
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the SQL profiler (in SQL Server) you can catch the SQL being sent from your app, copy, paste and run that directly in SQL Server query window and you should see any errors... Alternatively, add your data using a Stored Procedure, you'll find it is a lot easier to get working...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Monty, I tried with a stored procedure like you said, but it's the same thing, no answer when button click, it's like a new button with no code in it.

ALready delete the button and add a new one... and still not working, It doesn't fire the action

Comment: "It doesn't fire the action", then there is something else wrong with your project files... simplest thing to do would be to create a new VB.net project, Add a button, double click on it to create the event stub then put a break point in the code and run the app....

Comment: Also, i the above code, check that the Button on your Form is called 'btnSaveCust'